# Wait until process in remote server finishes using Fabric

Tags: python, server, wait, fabric, remote-server

### Setup

I am using [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to kick off a process on a remote server. My local server executes a Python file that runs three functions in sequence: the 1st and 3rd in the local server and the 2nd in the remote server, as follows.

**local_file.py**

```
local_function_1()
remote_function()
local_function_2()
```

The remote function is one specified in a local [fabfile](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/fabfiles.html), as follows.

**fabfile.py**

```
from fabric.api import *
@hosts(remote_server)
def remote_function():
    run('python function_on_remote_server.py')
```

### Question

`local_function_2` should run after `remote_function` has finished running, but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

I have considered (1) waiting a fixed number of seconds before `local_function_2` runs and (2) adding an intermediary local function that checks for the existence of some output from `remote_function` before running `local_function_2`.

**How can I delay the execution of a function on a local server until after a function on a remote server has finished running?**

Comment: As I understand from the documentation (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/tutorial.html#organize-it-your-way), this is the default behaviour of fabric: `"Fabric checks the return value of programs called via operations and will abort if they didn’t exit cleanly."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to change the way you're calling remote_function, and use Fabric `execute` instead.

```
from fabric.api import execute

local_function_1()
execute(remote_function)
local_function_2()
```

execute should block until the tasks complete.

For more info, see [Intelligently executing tasks with `execute`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute).

Comment: This is perfect and just what I was looking for. Thank you! Glad that this can be done in Fabric.